# Populate an array with Active Directory Group information

Tags: c#, arrays, active-directory

I want to have an array of information about my Active Directory groups.

The array will be a two dimensional array and will have four columns.

1. ID --> 1,2,3,... max ID depends of the number of groups
2. Name of the group
3. ID Parent --> if it's a parent group, add the number one
4. ID Child --> if it's a child of the previous parent group, add the number of the ID Parents.

I have already get the information with this code:

```
// Appel de la fonction GetDirectoryEntry
    DirectoryEntry entry = GetDirectoryEntry();

    // Création de l'objet de recherche
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

    // Filtre de recherche pour récupérer tous les groupes de l'AD commençant par All Of *
    search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(proxyAddresses=*)(name=All Of *))";

    SearchResultCollection results;
    // Results, contient tous les groupes commençant par All Of *
    results = search.FindAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Groups are a recursive structure. So you'll need to iterate recursively using the member property. Members can be users or other groups. So we need to filter the member collection

Instead an bidimensional array y have created the following structure, that allows to store parent-child relation:

```
class Group {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Members { get; set; }

    public Group() {
        Members = new List<Group>();
    }
}
```

And the search process can be something like this:

```
class Searcher {

    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public Searcher(string filter) {
        Filter = filter;
    }

    public List<Group> Search() {
        return Search(null, null);
    }

    protected List<Group> Search(string baseDn, int? parentId) {

        using (DirectoryEntry entryRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + baseDn)) {
            //We only iterate across groups (except root nodes)
            if (parentId.HasValue && !IsGroup(entryRoot))
                return null;

            using (DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher()) {
                search.Filter = $"(&(objectClass=group){Filter})";
                search.SearchRoot = entryRoot;

                SearchResultCollection results = search.FindAll();
                int i = 1;
                var groups = new List<Group>(results.Count);
                foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
                    using (DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetDirectoryEntry()) {
                        Group group = new Group {
                            Id = i,
                            Name = entry.Properties["cn"].Value.ToString(),
                            ParentId = parentId
                        };
                        var members = entry.Properties["member"];
                        foreach (string member in members) {
                            var subgroups = Search(member, i);
                            if (subgroups != null)
                                group.Members.AddRange(subgroups);
                        }
                        groups.Add(group);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                return groups;
            }
        }
    }


    private bool IsGroup(DirectoryEntry entry) {
        return entry.Properties["objectClass"].Cast<string>().Any(x => x == "group");
    }

}
```

Please note that DirectorySearcher and DirectoryEntry are both IDisposable, I haven't disposed them in sake of simplicity, but you should run `Dispose` on them once you're done with them.

If you really need an array, I think that is easy to iterate the recursively List

You can initialize Searcher as:

```
Searcher searcher = new Searcher("(proxyAddresses=*)(name=All Of *)");
var groups = searcher.Search();
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your fast reply. I still have a problem about your solution. As you mentioned, I initialized the Searcher like you said but my var groups variable still null after run. The only thing I changed is the following lines on Searcher Class:
`public List<Group> Search()
    {
        return Search("mybaseDn", null);
    }`
Another strange thing, when I try to debug the project, the debugger doesn't go throught the Searcher class and I don't know why.

Comment: If you need to search from a baseDN, you need to change the first part of the search function. I'll edit my response to reflect this

Comment: I have changed so all the recursive groups must match the filter conditios. Also I dispose the entryRoot and DirectorySearcher now.
If you need to filter in different way the child groups you can change the filter inside the if (parentId.HasValue && ...) line

Comment: Perfect, I did something great with your help. About the parentId variable, how can I have the good parentId for a member that is a child of him.
Example: 
Id = 1, Name = MyGroup,  ParentId = null
Id = 2, Name = MyChildOfMyGroup,  ParentId = 1

I cannot understand how to do that or how to use the parentId variable.

Comment: For example, you can ask for root nodes with linq: `groups.Where(x => x.ParentId == null)` or you can ask for child nodes with `groups.Where(x => x.ParentId.HasValue)`.
I' thinking, perhaps, a better aproximation whould be to store all elements in a unique List<Group>, removing the Members property. That will facilitate linq searchs.

Comment: I found a solution that did the job with your help. For my variable groups that contains all informations, how can I display it in a listbox or something like that ?